# Adding new id to references header using Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit

Is there any fancy method to add MessageIDs to references header?
Or is the only way to append id like this:

```
private void AppendIdToReferences(string id)
{
    MimeMessage mime = MimeMessage.Load(...);
    var references = mime.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == HeaderId.References);
    string refIds = references.Value + String.Format(" <{0}>", id);
    mime.Headers.Add(HeaderId.References, refIds);
}
```

When I just do like:

```
...
mime.Headers.Add(HeaderId.References, id);
...
```

Then the References seems to be blank for some reason? Shouldn' it a least contain the id added ?

Comment: Found i! How foolish of me... There is a property of MimeMessage called References which is a list of Ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be accessed by:
MimeMessage.Reference.Add(MessageID:"");